# SpringSecurity - RequestHeaderRequestMatcher

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I would like to configure my webapp, to reject all requests that don't have proper "Content-Type". for example: any content-type other than "application/json" should be rejected.

Currently I am doing it by a custom filter, but I would like to know how it can be done by "RequestHeaderRequestMatcher" in security config directly?

Lets' take the following example security config:

```
EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(matcher)
                .denyAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/index")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**")
                .hasRole("USER")

        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login-error")
    }
}
```

How should I add the new request matcher to check all requests for valid content type?

Answer (score 1):

One could use the [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestHeaderRequestMatcher.html) to verify that a request contains a certain header. Furthermore a more precise test could be made to test against a certain value as well.

In the following case all requests must contain an `Accept`-Header having the value `application/json`. Otherwise an HTTP-Status `406` is returned.

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Accept", "application/json"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this document [CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html) and  this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43559288/5429215

Comment: Not quite relevant. The question is about header (content-type) values, not the allowed headers.