# Spring with CORS origins site not working

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring 4.3.10.RELEASE and I have the current CORS configuration that I found in [Spring security CORS Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418441/spring-security-cors-filter)

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("https://google.com"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

If I use:

```
configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
```

I can do requests to my API from any site (as expected), but if I try to insert a site or two and request something from those sites, the "missing Access-Control-Allow-Origins" warning appears:

> Pedido de origem cruzada bloqueado: A política da mesma origem não permite a leitura do recurso remoto em https://localhost:8241/foo/. (Motivo: cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' em falta).
>
> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Is it something missing for this case?

Comment: Show the exact text, it isn't `https://google.com`, right? Did you add the right protocol and the right port?

Comment: The comment is in PT, sorry.

Comment: What is the value you wrote in your configuration? Is it also `https://localhost:8241/foo/`? However, it is very strange that you get `/foo/`, because it is not part of the host and should not part of the origin.

Comment: The https://localhost:8241 is where my API is deployed. Do I need to set this URL in the allowed origins too?

Comment: What is the real value of `configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("https://google.com"));`It should match your server host.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking. Sorry. Are you asking the value in the response header?