# Spring Boot CORS enable through configuration

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I've read many posts regarding CORS in Spring (Boot) but none could answer my question, but maybe I just missed the answer, so bear with me.
I have a REST Webservice currently used only for server to server calls. I now want to open some endpoints to be called directly from the browser, but not from the same domain, thus CORS. I got it working for some endpoints by doing two things:
1. enabling OPTIONS in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
   .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, 
                "/endpont1", 
                "/endpoint2")
   .permitAll()
```

2. adding the following annotation to my `@GetMapping` for these endpoints:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "${cors.origin}", allowCredentials = "true", 
                         exposedHeaders = ResponseUtils.CONTENT_DISPOSITION)
@GetMapping("/endpoint1")
```

The problem is, as far as I understand the documentation, leaving origins empty allows CORS for any domain. And I don't want to allow OPTIONS if I don't need CORS.

What is the best way to make this configurable through a properties file?

The "embedded" application.properties should have it disabled, but if the tenant wants to enable it we can provide an additional application-tenant.properties where we could enable it for certain domains and start the application with the appropriate profile.

EDIT: I found an answer in another post which looks interesting and maybe I can do this conditionally:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43559288/3737177

Answer (score 2):

After a few try and errors I found a working solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43559288/3737177) answer:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Order(1)
public class EndpointSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMatcher requestMatcher;

    @Value("${cors.origins:}")
    private String corsOrigins;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(corsOrigins)) {
            http.cors().configurationSource(buildConfigurationSource());
        }
        http.requestMatchers().mvcMatchers("/endpoint1", "/pendpoint2")
        .and().csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(requestMatcher)
        .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .hasAnyRole(SecurityConfiguration.ROLE_ENDPOINT_USER, SecurityConfiguration.ROLE_ADMIN)
        .and().httpBasic();
    }

    private CorsConfigurationSource buildConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(corsOrigins.split(",")));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET");
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/endpoint1", configuration);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/endpoint2", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

If there is a `cors.origins` property in the `application-tenant.properties`, it enables CORS and configures the allowed methods and headers. CSRF is also enabled for same origin requests.

Answer (score 1):

The truth is that you CANNOT set the global CORS configuration using the `application.properties` file. You HAVE TO use JavaConfig as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors).

```
implements WebMvcConfigurer
```

and override below method

```
 @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://domain4.com")
            .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
            .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
            .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(4200);
    }
```

Or 
Add below code snippet in Application.java

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
            }
        };
    }
```

I think this way you can add properties in a property file and use those in code here and based on different flavors you can override those properties.

Answer (score -1):

For loading custom properties files you can use
`spring.config.import=optional:classpath:cors.yml`
or from java args
`-Dspring.config.import=optional:classpath:cors.yml`
This method support reading from file, from url, repository and config server
[Spring documentation about this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#config-data-import)

For reading CORS configuration from properties file you may use library (I'm developer of this)

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.iruzhnikov</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc-cors-properties-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <version>VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

and properties config

```yml
spring:
  web:
    cors:
      enabled: true
      mappings: #spring.web.cors.mappings.<any_name>.<property>: <value>
        anyName: #just any name, just for grouping properties under the same path pattern (not used in internal logic)
          paths: #ant style path pattern, ATTENTION! not ordered, /** pattern override all other pattern
            - /path/to/api
            - /path/to/api/**
          #allowed-origins: "*"
          allowed-methods: GET #Enable override all defaults! If disabled: a lot more from all the controller methods included from the path pattern matches
          #allowed-headers: "*"
          #exposed-headers: ('*' - not-supported)
          #allow-credentials: true
          allowed-origin-patterns: .*
          #max-age: PT30M
```