# Added Spring Security CORS Filter- Dates retrieved from DB appear in Numeric Values

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I added these exact 2 classes to get around the CORS issue as suggested by Hendy Irawan here:
[Spring security CORS Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418441/spring-security-cors-filter)   **(1st) answer**.

Just one difference on the second class (`public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter`), I used `Arrays.asList("...")` instead of `ImmutableList.of("...")`

This is my Rest Controller

```
@RestController
public class UsersProfileController {
   @Autowired UserProfInterface userProfInterface;

   @GetMapping("/connector/{username}/users")
    public List<UserProfilesEntity> getAllUsers(
            @PathVariable String username) {
        return userProfInterface.getAllUsers();
    }
```

This returns a JSON like so:
`4: {idUserProfiles: 10, firstName: "Aris2", lastName: "Testy", dateOfBirth: 28936800000}`
`dateOfBirth` on MySQL DB looks like this: `1970-12-02`

**As soon as I disable Spring-Security dependency, Date of Birth appears correctly on the JSON file and  my front-end view (I am using Reactjs).**

My `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bootcamp</groupId>
    <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>connector</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am using `Spring Security` version 5.3.3

I have been a long time visitor here in Stackoverflow and this is my first time asking, so any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "@JsonFormat" to display as your expected. About spring security, I'm not sure if it affects the formatting of date