# Why I get cors error when submitting a request to secured resource in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have implemented spring security in my app using jwt token, I have the following configuration in spring security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(        
        prePostEnabled = true)  
public class MSSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    
    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
        
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
         web.ignoring().antMatchers("/companies/UnAuth/**");
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()           
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/companies/Auth/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/companies/Auth/Update").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/companies/Auth/Delete").authenticated();
        
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

I have the following cors annotation on the relevant controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/companies")
@Slf4j
public class CompanyController {
```

I tried to add the following to the http interceptor in angular:

```
authReq.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
    authReq.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

When submitting the request from Angular 9 app I can't pass the security and I get cors error:

```
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9001/companies/Auth/Update' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resourc`e.
```

Comment: Please read about CORS here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

Comment: I have the cors annotation, just added to the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring security CORS Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418441/spring-security-cors-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request doesn't contain the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, you should add it in the headers, it allows remote computers to access the content you send via REST.

**If you want to allow all remote hosts to access your api content you should add it like so:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

**Your can also specify a specific host:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
```

You should modify your dependencies in the pom.xml file and allow CORS headers, appart from the Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers there are a few more that you will need to add to the request, seek more info here:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework