# Override CORS policy in java springboot

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I am trying to have my frontend server pull an http request from my backend server, but am getting the following error in my browser console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/run' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I know this is a security protocol, but is there an easy way to override this issue and allow for port 8080 (my backend) to return calls from port (3000)?

edit: I am using java springboot as my backend framework and React as my frontend framework

edit 2: I installed and used the Moesif Origin & CORS Changer extension and it works, I just would like to know if there is a more permanent workaround.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418441/spring-security-cors-filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick approach is to add @CrossOrigin (import is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin) to your Rest Controller(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CRA proxy setting](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/), too.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).