# Springboot configuration 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have this configure method and i want to make user be able to register but i get 401 Unathorized. It is caused by the .apply(**) and i am not able to do it.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/signin").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider, securityUtils));
    }
```

JwtConfigurer.class

```
 public class JwtConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    private final SecurityUtils securityUtils;

    public JwtConfigurer(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider, SecurityUtils securityUtils) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
        this.securityUtils = securityUtils;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        JwtTokenFilter customFilter = new JwtTokenFilter(jwtTokenProvider, securityUtils);
        http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

So when request is sent to /auth/register i dont want to add .apply(**). Do u have any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` where your http `configure()` method with `.apply()` is written, you can use the following to tell Spring Boot to bypass or ignore the filter if encountered with the uri for user registration.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/auth/register");
}
```

Edit: Since you are facing the exception:

> Cross-origin Request Blocked (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing and Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

it means that your OPTIONS request (preflight request) is failing. Are you using a different project as Front End for your application? If yes, you will need to specify in your spring boot configuration to allow origin and allow the specified methods from that particular origin.

Please refer to this [official documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) to learn how to do that. You can enable Cors at Controller level or at global level. This [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418441/spring-security-cors-filter) should also be helpful in doing the implementation in case you are unable to proceed.

Comment: I was trying to do that but I got Cross-origin Request Blocked (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing and Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

Comment: @MatthewKulich - glad to hear that. Could you please consider marking this as accepted answer so that other users who may face the same issue will be able to resolve it?