# Getting "No 'Access-Control-Allowed-Origin' header is present" in react app + spring boot security app

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, cors

My spring boot app is running on `localhost:8080` and react app on `localhost:3000`.
I have configured the Outh2 in my spring boot app as follows:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/**")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3000/dashboard");
            .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(customOidcUserService); // checks if user exists in db, if not creates one
    
    return http.build();
}
```

I have a login button on page at `localhost:3000\login` which has its `href='http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/google'`. So when I click this button, it redirects to google, after authenticating to google, it redirects back to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` as stated in above config. On the load of `/dashboard` page , I am trying to fetch the data by first calling REST endpoint `localhost:8080/api/user`. The corresponding `RestController` looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SecController {
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public Map<String, Object> user(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) {
        return Collections.singletonMap("email", ((OidcUserPrincipal)principal).getUsername());
    }
}
```

But it gave me following error:

[image]

When I manually try to browse `localhost:8080/api/user`, it correctly returns currently logged in user information:

[image]

So, user is indeed getting correctly logged in. After googling for error, I added following bean as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418441/spring-security-cors-filter):

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD","GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

and also added `.and().cors()` in `filterChain()` method, but now it gives me following error:

[image]

Where did I make mistake?

**Update:**

I have following set in my google oauth client config:

[image]

[image]

However, it still gives same error.

Answer (score -1):

The error shows that accounts.google.com doesn't accept request from localhost.... try to configure your google api (oauth) to accept requests from your domain (i'm not sure it would accept "localhost" as a valid domain because of obvious security reasons)

Comment: Did you mean [this](https://i.postimg.cc/3x4mhJ3F/image.png)? With this too, am getting the same error. Also, please check the update at the bottom of the original question.

Answer (score -1):

The google login was successful, but still it was giving error that `Access to XMLHttpRequest at https://acounts/google.com/o/ouath2/v2/auth` was blocked. There was not reason to hit this URL after successful login. As error says, this URL was hit by redirection to `localhost:8080/api/user`. So somehow request to this URL did not have necessary information indicating earlier successful google login.

I checked the network traffic. The response from spring server after successful google login had `JSESSIONID` cookie. But afterwards, the request to `localhost:8080/api/user` did not have this cookie. So server was considering this as a new user request and trying to redirect it to google.

The request to `localhost:8080/api/user` was `HMLHttpRequest` using axios. So to include existing cookies to axios get request, I added following line before actually making the request:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

and now request to `localhost:8080/api/user` had `JSESSIONID` and hence it started working without any error.