# Spring Application has intermittent CORS errors which dissapear and reappear when editing webSecurityCustomizer

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I am working on a spring rest application which has multiple endpoints that need to be exposed to a browser frontend. All of these endpoints are working correctly and have no problem when using postman but when trying to call it from my flutter web frontend I receive CORS errors on some of my rest controllers but not on others. I have one rest controller which will give CORS errors on one instance but after a restart will function again without any code changes. I think the problem is how I configured my web security but I can't find a solution. Below is the code excerpt from my class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
    String jwkSetUri;
    
    
     @Bean
   public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
           return (web) -> web.ignoring()
                           .requestMatchers("/v3/*")
                           .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/*")
                                         .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")
                                        .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**");
   }

    

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
        .addFilterAfter(createPolicyEnforcerFilter(), BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    private ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter createPolicyEnforcerFilter() {
        return new ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter(new ConfigurationResolver() {
            @Override
            public PolicyEnforcerConfig resolve(HttpRequest request) {
                try {
                    return JsonSerialization.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/policy-enforcer.json"), PolicyEnforcerConfig.class);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(this.jwkSetUri).build();
    }

}
```

I have tried removing webSecurityCustomizer but then everything responds with a CORS error, I have also tried going to the individual rest controllers and giving them the annotation `@CrossOrigin(value = "*")` but I keep getting the same result. To confirm there is not anything other than CORS I opened up an instance of chrome with security disabled and everything functioned correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327308/cors-error-in-spring-oauth2 fixed my error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327308/cors-error-in-spring-oauth2 resolved my error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS error in Spring Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327308/cors-error-in-spring-oauth2)